# How do elemental damage buffs work with non-explicit skill runes?

Tags: diablo-iii

On my Crusader, i'm wearing some pieces of armor that add elemental bonus damage to certain skills (in this case, 19% holy damage, and 16% lightning damage). I understand that when a skill or skill rune explicitly states "damage turns into holy", like on Sweep Attack's *Gathering Sweep* rune, that will be affected by a buff to Holy elemental damage.

However, for other skills, there aren't clear indications like this. For example:
[image]

[image]

These skill runes have what appears to be a "holy" and "lightning" image behind them, similar to the *Gathering Sweep* rune, but don't explicitly state that their damage turns into holy or lightning.

So, **are skill runes that do not explicitly state their elemental damage, but still have an image LIKE an element, affected by elemental bonus damage?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What platform are you playing on? On PC, I see elemental tags explicitly listed for skill runes, like this:

[image]

I can tell you from experience that the answer to your question is **yes**: these runes convert the skill's damage to the listed element and will be affected by +elemental damage.

"Show Advanced Tooltips" under Options -> Gameplay toggles the display of this extra information. [image: Options/Gameplay]

Comment: I am on PC, odd that I don't see the same tag

Comment: The only thing I can think of: do you have "Elective Mode" enabled under Options -> Gameplay?

Comment: Indeed I do, definitely strange

Comment: Oh, wait, on the same screen there is "Show Advanced Tooltips". I just tried turning it off and the elemental tags went away for me.

Comment: Absolutely wild. I assumed that since it showed it by default for monks and wizards, it was just an oversight for other characters

Answer (score 3):

As you noticed, these runes have Holy and Lighting damage type icons and in fact do these types of damage accordingly. So they benefit from % bonus to elemental damage.

You can check [wiki](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Shield_Bash) for more detailed runes descriptions:

> Shattered Shield: increases the blast radius to 12 yards and the cone length to 30 yards, and damage to 740% plus 335% of Block Chance.

> One on One: damage type changes to Lightning, and primary target is also stunned for 1.5 seconds, while other affected enemies are knocked back up to 30 yards.